# VSCode видит ошибку там где её нет

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

вот код в котором НЕТ ошибки:

```
using System;

class Program{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("input:");
        string a = Console.ReadLine();   
        Console.WriteLine("output: " + a);
    }
}
```

если его запустить через `dotnet run` то код работает
но при этом VSCode видит в нем ошибку и подсвечивает `Console.ReadLine` буд то в нем есть ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как это можно исправить?

Comment: А если навести курсор мыши, во всплывающей подсказке будет какой-нибудь текст ошибки?

Comment: А где `namespace`? Хотя может и не в этом дело, но без него может быть всякое.

Comment: @andreymal да, вот 
The null literal or a possible null value is converted to a non-nullable type. [С#-first-prj]

Comment: @CrazyElf только что для теста поставил namespace, но это ничего не изменило

Comment: А, ну тогда это настоящая ошибка. Если по какой-то причине прочитать следующую строку не получится, то ReadLine вернёт null. Вероятно, замена `string a` на `string? a` исправит это

Comment: спасибо, string? помог, vscode перестал ругаться

Comment: Странно, у меня VSC на тот же код не ругается. А какое у вас расширение для C# стоит в VSC?

Comment: Хм, похоже и правда дело в `null`. В документации такой пример приведён: `while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null) ...` Хм, хотя при этом там `string line;`, т.е. если будет `null` то он спокойно в `string` попадёт. Ничего не понимаю.

Comment: @CrazyElf официальное разширение c#, стоит новый dotnet 6SDK

Comment: @CrazyElf nullable enable не забыли? У меня с ним dotnet run выплёвывает warning CS8600 (а с WarningsAsErrors вообще компилироваться перестаёт)

Comment: `string a = Console.ReadLine()!;`

Answer (score 0):

`String` ссылочный тип данных. Переменная такого типа не может быть проинициализирована с значением `null`, а также ей не может быть присвоен `null`.

Достаточно сделать переменную наллейбел добавив `?` к типу объявляемой переменной.

```
`string? a = Console.ReadLine();`
```

Comment: С чего это вдруг не поддерживает? То есть, по-вашему, `string value = null;` не поддерживается языком и должно привести к ошибке?  А если [проверим](https://dotnetfiddle.net/f75u1O)? Ну вы хотя бы проверили бы, изучили, почитали комментарии под вопросом, сразу поняли бы почему такое происходит. И да, не кажется странным конвертировать строку в строку? Ну ок, на вход вам поступает `null`, вы прогоняете его через конверт, что на выходе будет, ошибка, или значение? Пойдемте [тестировать](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0fxHDY). Так что, я думаю поняли почему ответ плохой?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ. Да, при тестах все работает, даже если подать нал, но перед предоставлением ответа я почитал официальную доку по ссылочным типам данных. И собственно говоря мой ответ из них и взялся. Думаю, первый пункт ответа можно убирать, но второй точно решает представленную проблему, не так-ли?

Comment: Решает, да, но зачем там конвертация из строки в строку? Вообще, если хотите сделать полноценный ответ, то прочитайте [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references), поймите сами из-за чего такое происходит и как решать, думаю много интересного найдете, да и дополните ответ)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ. Именно это я и читал, а также читал по строкам в частности. Видимо, не внимательно читал. Спасибо, что направили, ещё раз очень вам благодарен. aeport и вы 2 столпа на котором держится метка решетки). Пока подправлю ответ и уберу лишнее. Как докопаюсь до истины-дополню